# 2 entangled qubit gives all states with 25 %

Tags: python, quantum-computing, qiskit, qubit

We entangle two quarks; after measurement gives either |01> or |10> with probability of 50%.(regardless of their prior states ,they always give opposite states)

when I entangle 2 qubits using Cnot it gives |00> ,|01> ,|10> ,|11> all with 25% probability. why???

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The circuit you created is actually doing this: first, applying Hadamard gates to |00> will create the state 1/2(|00>+|01>+|10>+|11>). Then, applying the C-NOT will make |01> to |11> and |11> to |01> (normally |10> to |11> and |11> to |10> with textbook's convention but the Qiskit's convention makes it the other way), therefore your state actually is the same, that's why you get the 25% probability for each. I hope it is clear enough!

Comment: that means it is not same as real entanglement happen in quantum world. we are just flip one`s spin w.r.t. other.!!!!????

Comment: Actually it is the same, but may I suggest putting one X gate instead of the Hadamard gate on qubit 1? Then you would get the result you are trying to reach,  |01> or |10> with probability of 50%

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the 2-qubit system where we are applying Hadamard operator to both the qubits and then a CNOT (with the first qubit as the control bit).

[image]

With `qiskit` we can simulate the above system as shown in the code below and see that the results are as per our expectation (the output system is uniform superposition of 4 states with equal probability).

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, Aer, execute
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram

qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.h(0)  # |0> -> |+>
qc.h(1)  # |0> -> |+>
qc.cx(0,1)
qc.draw()
```

[image]

```
backend = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')
plot_histogram(execute(qc,backend).result().get_counts())
```

[image]

In order to get the desired states we need to apply a Hadamard gate (H) to the first qubit, a NOT (X) gate to the 2nd qubit and then apply CNOT to have desired entangled states (Bell State):

[image]

Simulating the above with `qiskit`:

```
qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.h(0)  # |0> -> |+>
qc.x(1)  # |0> -> |1>
qc.cx(0,1)
qc.draw()
```

[image]

```
plot_histogram(execute(qc,backend).result().get_counts())
```

[image]